# column does not exist in my table @Entity @Column

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, datasource

I have my entity called invoice and a column with the name "convenioPago" in the database but cannot find it

try to put `@Column (name = "\"convenioPago\"", nullable = false)`
but still with the same error

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice", schema = "public")
public class Invoice {
 //more columns
 @Column (name = "\"convenioPago\"", nullable = false)
 private Long convenioPago;
}
```

I also use @Configuration to create my datasource

```java
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"package.repository"})
@Configuration
public class Config {
 @Bean
 public DataSource dataSource(){
   DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
   //use org.postgresql.Driver
 }
```

Note: I use spring-boot-starter-parent 2.1.7.RELEASE

The error I have is:
`ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: ERROR: column invoice0.convenio_pago does not exist`

Because it refers to `convenio_pago` if it should be to `convenioPago`?

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: Hi @YCF_L I use Relational

Comment: I mean MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, also can you show us how you create the table please

Comment: ooh! sorry I use POSTGRES, the table was created many years ago using MyEclipseCI but I have a microservices project with that table and I mapped it. The entity is https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/2v97

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353492/jpa-uppercase-table-names

Comment: Hi @YCF_L I use `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect` in my application.yml. I also mentioned that my datasource is from `@Configuration`

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376093/hibernate-column-name-issues/376118. Also, Hibernate is doing what's perferred. Still, you could enclose your column name in extra quotes to acheive what you need

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot Hibernate 5 Ignoring @Table and @Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41912028/spring-boot-hibernate-5-ignoring-table-and-column)

Comment: Hi @YogeshPatil my application.yml is: https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/2v9a. I use  `org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl`

Comment: Hi, @MartinvanWingerden,  his answer is almost solving me, now he doesn't show me the "_", the output now is that he doesn't find `conveniopago` but it should be `convenioPago`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Hibernate native API, then you can escape them using backticks:

```
@Column(name = "`convenioPago`")
private Long convenioPago;
```

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, I also used "`", but it gives the same result.

Comment: So as yogesh commented a link. Looks like you should just use "convenioPago" and this should work.

Comment: @MaicolyMorocho please try it and let me know if that works.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, i have the same error, `ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : ERROR: no existe la columna factura0_.convenio_pago Hint: Probablemente quiera hacer referencia a la columna «factura0_.convenioPago».`

Comment: factura0=invoice0 :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @MartinvanWingerden, your comment helped me to the solution!
My solution:
In my @Configuration, i need this jpaproperties.

```
Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy","org.hibernate.cfg.ImplicitNamingStrategy");
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.physical_naming_strategy","org.hibernate.cfg.PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl");
```

and the dialect:

```
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
```